# how to show equivalence of arbitrary chosen element of a set.

Tags: analysis

Given a set $S\in \mathbb{R}$, let us write $−S$ for the set $\{−x \mid x\in S\}$. Prove that if $S$ is bounded below then $−S$ is bounded above.

This is not a hard problem, but I am puzzled by the follow:

I assumed $x$ is an arbitrary element in $S$, and let $L$ be an lower bound for $S$. Thus, $x\geq L.$ so $-x\leq -L.$ Now the problem is how do you show $-x$ covers all the elements of $-S$. I mean, $x$ is an element of $S$, but now how do you show $-x$ also represent every element of $-S$?

Answer (score 1):

You already proved it:

$$x\ge L\;\;\text{forall}\;\;x\in S\iff -x\le -L\;\;,\;\text{forall}\,-x\in-S$$

Answer (score 0):

You take an arbitrary element $y\in -S$ and you prove that $y\leq -L$.

Now, since $y\in -S$ you know that there exists such an $x\in S$ that $y=-x$. You know this because the very definition of $S$ is:

> All such values that can be written as $-x$ for some value of $x\in S$

And since $x\geq L$, you know that $-x \leq -L$, thus, $y\leq -L$ is true for an arbitrary $y\in-S$.

Comment: I am still puzzled.  Can you please write $y$ all in terms of $-x$? I hope you can write it a complete proof please. I appreciate your help!